# Upload file into Sharepoint Document set

Tags: document, file-upload, client-object-model

I'm trying to upload a file to a document set which is located in a library.

Im using C# and the Sharepoint Client Object Model - Library, but I can not find any documentation to do this task.

I know how to upload the file itself to the library's root, but I did not find any possibility to upload it to a document set yet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to upload file into Document Set using SharePoint 2010/2013 CSOM

```
/// <summary>
/// Upload file into Document Set
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list">List Title</param>
/// <param name="docSetName">DocumentSet Name</param>
/// <param name="fileName">File name to upload</param>
private static void UploadFileIntoDocumentSet(List list,string docSetName, string fileName)
{
    var ctx = list.Context;
    ctx.Load(list.RootFolder);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
        var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,docSetName, fi.Name);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, fileUrl, fs, true);
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
 using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
 {
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
     UploadFileIntoDocumentSet(list,"Orders", @"C:\Order.docx");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Document sets are somewhat similar to Folders in Document library.
In below code we set the path to document set and upload Files to it:

```
//Declare path to document set
            SPFolder myLibraryToUploadDocument = spWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName].SubFolders[txtTitle.Text];
            // Prepare to upload
            Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
            String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullPathFileName);
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fullPathFileName);
            // Upload document
            SPFile spfile = myLibraryToUploadDocument.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);
            // Commit
            myLibraryToUploadDocument.Update();
```

[Source]http://www.microsofttechnology.net/2012/03/article-3-create-new-document-sets-and.html